# Best way to dynamically alter part of Grunt config before calling specific tasks

Tags: build, gruntjs

In my Gruntfile I have pieces of config which are initialised after analyzing some external information.
Those dynamic parts of config are needed only by specific tasks, and, since generating them is not completely cheap operation.
My question is - what is the best way to change/add grunt config just before some specific task is called.

What I've tried so far.
My first attempt was based on following idea:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        log: {foo: 'This should be overridden'}
    }); 


    grunt.task.registerMultiTask('log', 'Log stuff.', function() {
          grunt.config.set('log.foo', 'log.foo overriden!');
          grunt.log.writeln(this.target + ': ' + this.data);
    }); 

    grunt.registerTask('default', 'log');
};
```

This failed, but give me a hint on how to make a working decision:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        log: {foo: 'This should be overridden'}
    }); 


    grunt.task.registerTask('logWrapper', 'Log stuff.', function() {
          grunt.config.set('log.foo', 'log.foo overriden!');
          grunt.task.run('log');
    }); 

    grunt.task.registerMultiTask('log', 'Log stuff.', function() {
          grunt.log.writeln(this.target + ': ' + this.data);
    }); 
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'logWrapper');
};
```

Though this works, but looks overcomplicated and a quite impractical.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way as well:

```
grunt.task.registerTask('logWrapper', 'Log stuff.', function() {
      grunt.config.set('log.foo', 'log.foo overriden!');
}); 
grunt.registerTask('default', ['logWrapper','log']);
```

Otherwise these pages can be useful:

- http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks
- http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks

Comment: well, you actually moving log call, that's it, nothing had changed conceptually.

Comment: I think creating a separate task for doing the config changing adds more flexibility. You can add the new task if you need it, but you don't have to.

Comment: ah, can see what you mean, agreed.

Answer (score 1):

[grunt.option](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt#grunt.option) can be a clean way to handle dynamic tasks.

Give `log` a template with a grunt option in it:

`log: "<%= grunt.option('log') || {foo: \'This should be overridden\'} %>'`

and override in a wrapper or other task with `grunt.option('log', {foo: 'newvalue'})`.

Comment: Thank you for this response. But what benefits this gives compared to just setting grunt.config.set?

Comment: Flexibility, mostly. Commandline flags can be used to set grunt.option values, in addition to being able to set them from within other tasks. Setting the template to just the value of `foo`, you can execute `grunt task --foo=bar` and run with that as `foo`'s definition.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is exactly this extremely rare case when I feel I've found the better solution than that that've been provided here.

We can use getters:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        get log() { 
            grunt.log.writeln('Dynamic config');
            return {
                foo: 'This will be called only when log task is called'
            }   
        }   
    }); 

    grunt.task.registerMultiTask('log', 'Log stuff.', function() {
          grunt.log.writeln(this.target + ': ' + this.data);
    }); 

    grunt.task.registerTask('dummy', 'Just a dummy task', function() {
          grunt.log.writeln('Hey! I\'m dummy!');
    }); 

};
```

`grunt log` will trigger log evaluation, while `grunt dummy` won't.